# Add submit button to HTML form

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a simple form with four input field (contact id, tel number, name, salutation). if i input 'contact id' & press Enter button, the rest of the field will auto filled retrieve from DB. now I want to add a 'submit' button to the form, so that those info can be save to another DB table by clicking on that button. i've tried to add the button, but the auto fill function is not working anymore. anyone can help? thanks in advance :)
here is my index.html file:

```
<html> 
    <body> 
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function ajaxFunction(e){
    var e=e || window.event;
    var keycode=e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(keycode==13 || (e.target||e.srcElement).value==''){ 
    var http;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible! 

    try{ 
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } catch (e){ 
        // Internet Explorer Browsers 
        try{ 
            http = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } catch (e) { 
            try{ 
                http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
            } catch (e){ 
                // Something went wrong 
                alert("Your browser broke!"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        }
    }

    var url = "getagentids.php?param=";
                var idValue = document.getElementById("agid").value;
                var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999);  // cache buster
                http.open("GET", "getagentids.php?param=" + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true);
                http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse;
                http.send(null);
         function handleHttpResponse() {
                    if (http.readyState == 4) {
                        results = http.responseText.split(",");
                        document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[0];
                        document.getElementById('agsal').value = results[1];
                        document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
                        document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
                    }
                } 
    }
}

</script> 

       <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Contact ID:</td>
                    <td><input id="agid" type="text"
                               name="contactid" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(event)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tel Number:</td>
                    <td><input id="agtel" type="text"
                               name="contacttel"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="agfn" type="text"
                               name="contactfullname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salutation:</td>
                    <td><input id="agsal" type="text"
                               name="contactsalutation"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Use `type="button"` and use `jQuery` or `Javascript` to submit form

Comment: thanks for reply.. :)
any example to refer?

Comment: http://www.daftspunk.com/code/really-simple-ajax-contact-form-using-jquery-and-php.html

Comment: @GBD

it seems complex to me because i'm not much familiar with jQuery :( any other way please? btw, did you check my index file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the submit button *after* you populate the form, you can do this by a using `innerHTML`

```
...
if (http.readyState == 4) {
   results = http.responseText.split(",");
   document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[0];
   document.getElementById('agsal').value = results[1];
   document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[2];
   document.getElementById('agid').value = results[3];
   document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>";  // add Submit button by innerHTML
}
...
```

And in your table add a `<div id="buttons">` to where you want to add the `submit` button

```
<tr>
    <td><div id="buttons"></div><input type="reset" value="Clear"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: yeah mate, you got my point :) i want to add the submit button after populate the form. i tried what you told but no luck :(

Comment: Are your form fields populating and just the adding of the submit button not working, or is the populating not working either?

Comment: when i add the button & set the form action, the populating isn't working anymore..

Comment: How are you setting the form action?

Comment: its like '<form action="insert.php" method="post">' & the submit button is like '<td><div id="buttons"><input type="submit"></div></td>'